# Is it right to say: "did anybody made you angry today"?

Tags: structure, sentence

Is it right to say: did anybody made you angry today?

Comment: No, it is not right.

Comment: Why do you doubt this particular sentence.  What part of it are you unsure about? Has someone told you it is wrong?  Is there some rule of grammar that you think might be broken?  Saying "Here is a sentence. Is it right" is not a useful or complete question.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Actually, I think it's wrong. Rather it should be: did anybody "make" you angry today? I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Do* (does,did, don't, didn't) is **always** followed by the base form the verb, never by the past participle.

So, *Did anybody **make** you angry today?*

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate this answer